# Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL миграции flask

Tags: python, база-данных, веб-программирование, flask

Я добавил поле в модель и ЯВНО указал параметр по умолчанию, вот таким образом:

```
lease_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

Но при попытке миграции всё равно выводит вот такую простыню:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL
[SQL: ALTER TABLE contract ADD COLUMN lease_date DATETIME NOT NULL]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Как можно исправить эту ошибку? (Я использую flask sqlalchemy и субд sqllite).

Comment: У вас точно поля `lease_date` никогда раньше не существовало?

Comment: Да, только сейчас добавил.